# How to append dataframes from different files, but having same structure?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have different datasets in a json format, with each file containing different matches details but have the same column names. I've isolated the 'Shots' taken by one team in a single match. How should i modify my code to take only the shots of that particular team for different matches.

```
def key_pass(filename):
with open(filename) as f:
    comp = json.load(f)
eng = pd.json_normalize(comp)
for team in eng['possession_team.name'].unique():
    if team != 'Belgium':
        opp = team
eng = pd.json_normalize(comp).assign(Oppn = opp)
eng_pan = eng[['shot.statsbomb_xg','minute','player.name','shot.outcome.name','shot.key_pass_id','location','type.name','play_pattern.name','possession_team.name']]
eng_pan.rename(columns={'shot.statsbomb_xg':'Statsbomb_xG','shot.outcome.name':'Outcome','shot.key_pass_id':'Keypass_id'})
total_attempts = eng_pan.loc[(eng_pan['type.name'] == 'Shot') & (eng_pan['possession_team.name'] == 'Belgium')]
total_attempts.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)

return(total_attempts)
```

When i Call the function,

```
total_attempts = key_pass('7584.json')
total_attempts
```

The Output I get is,
[image]

Now, if i have to call another file, I need the shots from that file to continue from where the previous file has finished.
Should i pass the file names as list ? And add a for loop in the function, but then again how do i append the shots ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pandas DataFrame append method easily if both df's have the same structure:
(notice the ignore index parameter)

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=list('AB'))
df
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[5, 6], [7, 8]], columns=list('AB'))
   A  B
0  5  6
1  7  8


df.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4
2  5  6
3  7  8
```

Comment: But for this I need to create different dataframes for different matches, right ? I just need a single dataframe where i've written the code to separate the 'Shots' alone. I need to know how to add to the existing df instead of creating a new df and appending it?

Comment: If you want to avoid creating new df's for each file read you use the output of: comp = json.load(f)  (it might be a python dict or list, depends on the json structure ) and use the same append command as I originally posted.

Comment: Thanks Bukka, I inserted the append to my function, called it using a list and then created an empty df for appending and it works fine !!